# Objects all moving together

Tags: objects, transforms, 3d-manipulator

Every time I use the 3d manipulator it moves all of the other objects in the scene:
[image: objects in scene]

They are multiple meshes and the image illustrates the way they move at different speeds

Comment: Perhaps you have everything selected? Maybe they are all joined together as one object? Maybe they are all parented to what you are trying to move? Try hitting "A" to deselect everything. Select everything and hit "Alt-P" to clear any parent relations. Try going into "Edit" mode to see if your objects are actually one object.

Comment: How can *image* illustrate how objects move at different speed ? Record a short animation of that using [gif recording](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) to showcase the problem and [upload your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). If linked question doesn't answer your question, then yours one is still unclear.